# Cannot find module '@firebase/app-types/private' - install older version not working

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

I am working on application using angular and firebase. There was no problem with my firebase version until yesterday when it began to throw an error

> ERROR in
>   node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/esm/src/api/Database.d.ts(4,33):
>   error TS2307: Cannot find module '@firebase/app-types/private'.
>   node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/esm/src/core/AuthTokenProvider.d.ts(17,39):
>   error TS2307: Cannot find module '@firebase/app-types/private'.

My package.json config is :

> "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.4", 
>   "firebase": "4.8.0"

I know it's a known issue, but I tried all the solutions I found and they are all the same : downgrade firebase version. I tried everything and it's still not working.

I don't know what I can do from here nor where the problem comes from...

Comment: Can you run `npm ls firebase` on your app's directory?

Comment: yes i can...  

angularfirebase@0.0.0 c:\users\julie\angularfirebase
-- firebase@4.8.0